# pipe tcp client data to http response ,get: 'res not defined'

Tags: node.js, http, tcpclient

how to pipe tcp client data into http response ?
cannot find complete example for that.

```
var oHttp = require("http")
    oHttp.createServer(function(req, res)
    {
    var query = req.url.split('?')[1];
    oTCP.write(query +'\n') ;
    }).listen(port);
```

get data from tcp client to http 'res' object using pipe :

```
var oNet  = require('net');
    oTCP = new oNet.Socket();
    oTCP.connect(PORT, HOST, function()
{
    console.log('TCP.client listen at port ' + PORT )
    this.pipe(res);
    });
```

got an error from node.js the 'this.pipe(res);' not defined on the object 'res'

what I want to achieve is :

1. declare http serever
2. connect once to tcp client.
3. from http serever (req,res) cycle
   write to tcp client some query string
4. get response from tcp client with pipe ,
   to bypass the all on('data',...) event handlings
   so the pipe will 'know to target stream to 'res' streamer, if I understand.

in all the examples I see, that develoeprs are putting the tcp.connect inside the scope
   of the HTTP.createServer loop cycle ??
   so it will make tcp connect on each (req,res) ?

I need make on once TCP connect and pipe to HTTP response's after each TCP.client write.

Comment: You need to put it in the server's [scope.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: so it will make tcp connect on each request ?

Comment: Also there is no 'res streamer'. You can only send the response to the client once, unless you use polling or websockets.

Comment: ofcourse to send, the pipe to http response once , I ask about the tcp connect once , not on each http request, if I udnerstand correctly the node.js cycle